# fetch rawg API with javascript results in error

Tags: javascript

i have some problem to fetch the rawg api, i get everytime the message

```
{
    "error": "The key parameter is not provided"
}
```

i'm trying to fetch with postman with a GET request to:

```
https://api.rawg.io/api/games/?key=< my RawG Api Key >&search=crash
```

i can't find related documents about this. any help is appreciated.

this is my first attempt but does not show only 1 result

```
fetch('https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=75a9ffdcf4444e1896ead6e467b985e8&page_size=1&count=1&/call of duty')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
https://api.rawg.io/api/games/?key=< my RawG Api Key >&search=crash
```

remove `/` after `games`

```
https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=< my RawG Api Key >&search=crash
```

Comment: i do not want to publish my apikey, but in my request there is an api key there

Comment: answer is edited, please check now

Comment: oh my god....thanks....i feel stupid right now

Comment: the result in this json is a little bit complicated btw, how can i get only 1 result? i've tried with page_size params but not work...  (edited answer)

Comment: share your json result plz..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dg4c6t3h/  how to get only image, rating and description only in english (i think italian is not available)

Comment: please post another question on stackoverflow, put answer in comment is difficult...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69366592/display-rawg-api-json-output-into-html my friend made the request for me