# Display rawg api json output into html

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to access the rawg api and then display these data:

- game image
- game description
- game rating

and i've made a request like this (api key is fake because i can't post data here):

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page_size=1&search=call of duty modern warfare&key=75a9ffdcf4444e1896ead6e555b966e8',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (results) {
          console.log(results)
```

the json output is:
https://jsfiddle.net/xyfvt1L8/

how can i display these info in html? (i can't find description and rating)

and results.name does not display anything (return undefined)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data has field `results` is a `array`, you can use loop to show your whole data, otherwise you can use index
like `results.results[0].name`,  `results.results[0].rating`.
there is not `description` in your api response, if you really need  this, contact with API provider.